# Error Upload Project Laravel to Web

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just finished building my Laravel 5 project and amd trying to upload it to the internet. I upload all of my files, it shows me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/laderra2/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 381

Here's my directory of my Laravel Project:

[image]

In this project I'm not using public folder to access my resource file. I tried to copy my list directory and file into `public_html` and get an error from this function :

```
function resource($name, $controller, array $options = []){
  return app('router')->resource($name, $controller, $options);
}
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: what's your php version in host?

Comment: which version of php is installed on the remote server? Seem <5.5 (this tipe of  array definition went introduced in this release and it is the minimun requirement for laravel 5)

Comment: Current version from my hosting php is 5.3, how solution for that?

Comment: Upgrade the PHP version on your host.

Answer (score 0):

Short array syntax has been added in PHP since version 5.4.0.

```
e.g. $a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; or $a = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4];.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function resource($name, $controller, array $options = array())
{
    return app('router')->resource($name, $controller, $options);
}
```